# C Linked List (FILE)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Problem : I need to pull up the information in the text file , however it's producing a different output. it says incompatible pointer type. when i check the text file the information encoded was saved correctly however when i tried to view the saved data from the text file using the viewVoter() function it shows different symbols.. i'm just new in the field of programming any feedback or answer will be highly appreciated.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct Voter{
       char VFname[25];
       char VMname[25];
       char VLname[25];
       char Course[25];
       short Vyearlevel;
       short RegNumber;
       struct Voter *next;
};

typedef struct Voter* Voters;

Voters top = NULL;

Voters Addvoter(){ 


          Voters newVoter = (Voters)malloc(sizeof(struct Voter)); 

             printf("\t\t|-----------------Voter----------------|\n");
             printf("\t\t|-----------Registration Form--------------|\n");
             printf("\t\t|-----------Add New Voter Detail-----------|\n"); 
             printf("|-----------TYPE THE INFORMATION BESIDE THE REQUIRED FIELD-----------|\n\n\n");

             printf("First Name:");  
             scanf("%s",newVoter->VFname); 

             printf("Middle Name:");  
             scanf("%s",newVoter->VMname);

             printf("Last Name:");
             scanf("%s",newVoter->VLname);

             printf("Course:");
             scanf("%s",newVoter->Course);

             printf("Yearlevel:");
             scanf("%i",&newVoter->Vyearlevel);

             printf("Registration Number:");
             scanf("%i",&newVoter->RegNumber);


FILE *List_Voter;

             List_Voter = fopen("Voters.txt","a+");

             fprintf(List_Voter,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%i\t%i\n",&newVoter->VFname,newVoter->VMname,newVoter->VLname,newVoter->Course,newVoter->Vyearlevel,newVoter->RegNumber);

             fclose(List_Voter);

             printf("Voter Successfully Registered!!\n");

             newVoter->next=NULL; 

             return newVoter;

             }

void viewVoter(void)
{

                    FILE *List_Voter;

                    List_Voter=fopen("Voters.txt","r");

                    Voters newVoter = (Voters)malloc(sizeof(struct Voter)); 

                    while(!feof(List_Voter)){

                    fscanf(List_Voter,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%i\t%i\n",&newVoter->VFname,&newVoter->VMname,
                    &newVoter->VLname,&newVoter->Course,&newVoter->Vyearlevel,&newVoter->RegNumber);

                    printf(List_Voter,"%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%i\t%i\n",&newVoter->VFname,&newVoter->VMname,newVoter->VLname,newVoter->Course,newVoter->Vyearlevel,
                    newVoter->RegNumber);

                    newVoter->next=NULL;

}
                    fclose(List_Voter);        
}
```

Comment: No input is different in itself. Different from **what?** (Furthermore, `scanf()` and company are very-very bad, and quite naturally, you just failed to use them correctly. I suggest `fgets()` instead.)

Comment: Please compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: btw i'm using dev c as a compiler.

Comment: @user3477950 what i mean is that, when i save the information let say "John Smith" it will be saved in the text file properly but when i tried to pull up the information it just shows different symbols

Comment: @user3526977 You mean Dev-C++? that's not a compiler. that's an IDE.

Comment: @user3526977 thank you ;) i'll make sure to use the correct term next time

Comment: @user3526977 FYI, the compiler that Dev-C++ uses is generally the MinGW port of the GCC toolchain.